# How do I make a command to display a custom title page?

Tags: macros, titles

I followed the advice on the question [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) to try to make a custom command that displays a custom title page, but it is not working.

```
./article.tex:17: You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.\@ ->\spacefactor
                  \@m
l.17 \makecustomtitle

Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.
./article.tex:17: Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>
                $
l.17 \makecustomtitle

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
./example.tex:17: You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.\@ ->\spacefactor
                  \@m
l.17 \makecustomtitle

Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.
./example.tex:17: Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>
                $
l.17 \makecustomtitle

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

What follows is the simplified code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\makecustomtitle}{
\begin{titlepage}
  \makeatletter

  \@title by \@author

  \makeatother
\end{titlepage}
}

\begin{document}
\title{Please, be my title}
\author{Andres Riofrio}

\makecustomtitle

Take on me.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to move the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` outside of the `\newcommand`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makecustomtitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
    \@title by \@author
  \end{titlepage}
}
\makeatother
```

The difference is that in the above set-up the category codes are changed at the time of definition; in your set-up they were attempting to change at the time of use.

Note that I've also added `%` to the end of the first line. Have a look at these links:

- [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)
- [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

Comment: Actually, those `%` characters are useless in this particular example: vertical mode, where spaces are ignored, is in force after `\begin{titlepage}` and `\end{titlepage}`. It's not necessary after `\@author`, because spaces are ignored after control sequences. It's not necessary when ending a definition in the preamble. The only sensible place is after the `{` that starts the definition, but in this particular case it's not needed either, as the command will be given in vertical mode. :)

Comment: That was very useful. Thanks! In the end I also put the code in an .sty file, not needing `\makeatletter` anymore.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for details! Please feel free to edit, or let me know if I should.